# HTML Select specific element with no class

Tags: html, css

As the title says, I don't know how to only select the first h1 "I want to select this"

Specially using no classes, only the first h1 from the HTML text

Comment: Use first-of-type selector https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]

Answer (score 0):

Very simple [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will do

```js
// first h1 in header

console.log(
  document.querySelector("header > h1").textContent
)

// first h1 in document:

console.log(
  document.querySelector("h1").textContent
)
```

```css
header > h1 {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>I want to select this</h1>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the world!</h1>
    <p>I don't like apples</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
h1:first-of-type{

}
```

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this , select parent then select the first child of type h1

```css
   header > h1:first-child{
       color:red;
   }
```